# Apache Poi - Get hyperlink and put it into a new cell with certain String

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to fetch Hyperlinks and Strings from a cell in Apache Poi.

```
Cell cell = pair.getKey();

System.out.println(cell);
```

[image]

As you can see, this data exists in the cell object.

I know that I can get the String with the getStringCellValue() method.

getHyperlink() returns null though. But as you can see, the hyperlink exists. How do I get it?
And how can I transform it to put it into another cell with the setCellValue() Method with the text of the fetched string ?

Comment: That looks like it might be a `HYPERLINK` formula, could that be it? If so, try getting the formula out?

Comment: Wow, you are right! Huge thanks! Now I can at least manipulate the String. Tomorrow I will try to copy it into another cell with the hyperlink underneath a String